# What size grounding rod(s) for 100A subpanel in Northern NJ

Tags: electrical-panel, grounding

The house we bought has a detached garage built from cinder blocks perhaps 50+ years ago (with no copper plumbing), and had only one 20A line installed underground from the home. I'd like to install a 100A subpanel in the garage so I'll be able to add additional circuits, including for EVs. What diameter & length grounding rod(s) for a 100A sub panel are required in Northern NJ?

If it matters, the garage is 70 ft from the home, and the home has a 200A panel. I'm planning to run about 111 ft of 3-3-3-5 SER copper underground cable (depth of 2 ft) from the home.

Comment: Why waste money on copper SER? Aluminum 1-1-1-3 is 1/3 the price, and 2-2-2-4 is even cheaper if you can live with 90A. If you heard bad things about aluminum, "that which you heard" never applied to heavy feeder like this. Heck, the wire is landing on lugs made of aluminum.  However, you may want to consider conduit. Much easier to maintain. I know everyone's plan is to not have a problem, but rocks don't listen lol.

Comment: Also, ordinary SER cable *cannot* be used underground, even inside a conduit.  You need special dual-rated TC-ER/SER cable for that (Encore Wire's the only folks who make it, and it's not exactly trivial to find as a result).   Of course, you could use a direct bury multiplex cable (USE-2 or MHF) for this job, instead....

Comment: Another question: is the existing 20A circuit to the garage run using direct bury cable, or individual wires in a conduit?

Comment: Agreed that AL is much more cost effective than copper, it works fine as long as you put the "goop" (NoAlox) compound on it.   I also agree that putting it in conduit is a good idea, but have you priced conduit lately!?  It's outrageous.  A 10' stick of 1 1/2 is $27  That's almost $200 just for the conduit. Not sure of the size needed for the OP's project, maybe they could go down to 1 1/4".  Get this 3" conduit is $86 for a 10' stick.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson is NoAlox necessary for feeder cable when landing AL wire on AL lugs in a panel?

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, you always need it on the connections.  The best way to apply it is to slightly spread the individual strands in the wire apart and use a small wire brush to thoroughly infuse it with the goop, then push them back together to their original shape and insert it into the connection.   AL WILL OXIDIZE and create a problem unless you use the goop!  Good question, BTW   +

Comment: Fair enough, @GeorgeAnderson, thanks for the clarification. I would never have thought of that.

Comment: @FreeMan   What you might be thinking of is electrolysis, where two dissimilar metals are connected.  Common in plumbing if you need to connect a copper pipe to steel (galvanized)  pipe you need a dielectric union to prevent electrolysis.   Yes,  most connectors in panels are AL, so no dissimilar metals here.  What we are dealing with is oxidation which is basically the equiv of rust on steel.   The NoAlox compound prevents the oxidation and works very well.

Comment: I appreciate all of the input. @ThreePhaseEel the initial 20A cable had no conduit & was directly under the driveway nowhere close to today's code. I'll probably look into running conduit & individual wires. My initial request was for what size grounding rod. Can somebody give me some input on grounding rod diameter & length?

Comment: @FreeMan Code does not require the NoAlox (unless the connector *is supplied with* NoAlox, in which case you must renew it if it is depleted).  However, if someone advises using it, I definitely won't argue. I would really want it on Cu wire/Al lug, for reasons which I trust are entirely obvious lol. However it does not allow AL wire on a lug not rated for Al wire.

Comment: Thanks, @Harper-ReinstateMonica, I appreciate the code note, too.. The CU/AL situation I was aware of, I didn't realize that it was also appropriate for AL/AL connections - I just wouldn't have thought it was necessary, but George's feedback makes sense.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson, I see your point about conduit prices. Wow! If I use AWG 3 for the 3 wires, and AWG 5 bare copper for the ground, what size SCH 40 conduit do you think should be used? I've seen conduit calculators online, but don't exactly understand their terminology (#3 vs 3/0, etc.). Thanks also for answering my grounding question!

Comment: WOW, so many opinions on this.  A copper conductor (wire) will never require NoAlox even if connected to an AL fitting.  it would be worthless bc copper doesn't oxidize and even if it did, NoAlox wouldn't be the right stuff to prevent it.   @Harper-ReinstateMonica  you are a bright guy and I respect almost all of your answers, but in this case, I stand by my previous statement that the goop (NoAlox) is mandatory on all AL feeder connections, regardless of the terminal / connection receiving the wire.

Comment: 1 1/4 would be the smallest you could go with according to the table on the link below.  But I'd go with 1 1/2" to be safe and make for an easier pull.   

https://solutions.borderstates.com/resource/conduit-fill-table/

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Thanks a million. I still don't understand how to read the chart, and appreciate your translation.

Comment: @George I never meant to contradict you on "use noalox".  However copper can corrode in adverse environments including dissimilar metals... and more on-point, the aluminum lug can corrode all by itself! The one in the photo did. So noalox never hurts and can help, as you say.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  No worries, I didn't take it that way, I'm not a snowflake!  Clarification:?!?   I thought NoAlox was strictly for AL, but I might be wrong.  Can it also be used on copper?   Or is there a different "goop" for copper?  I just did some research and there is tons of opinions out there if NoAlox is good for copper or not.   But in most cases, they say even if it's not necessary, it can't hurt.

Comment: @George I said that because earlier, I had contradicted myself saying I would never call you wrong except I just had lol.  Don't think of it as using noalox on the copper wire, think of it as using it on the aluminum lug. (where it meets the wire).  Many connectors (e.g. Polaris) are pre-loaded with Noalox, and they don't know you're using it with copper wire! LOL (the connector is aluminum)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Again, absolutely no worries.  I'm not perfect, I actually made a mistake one time last year!  (ROFL!!!!)  Of course I'm kidding.  But I will admit that when I make a mistake woodworking, I call it a "design opportunity".   Using current woke lingo, I "identify the mistake as a design opportunity".  Enjoy.  I also like reading your posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To actually answer your question (lots of comments about the wire, but none about your question):  I'm pretty sure a ground rod is a ground rod, is a ground rod.  In just about all cases, for an outbuilding, you need 2 ground rods at least 8' long spaced at least 6' apart (further is better). There is a ton of info here on SE regarding sub-panels. Do a quick search and you'll find everything you need to know.

In doing some research, I ran across this article, which may help you:  https://galvanelectrical.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/groundrodmarkingcompliance.pdf  So I'm not entirely correct in saying there's no difference.  Once again, as we say here often, the AHJ is the final say for where you live.